# How to extract computed style values from HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following function to get all the HTML elements with a certain computedStyle. FOr example `getCssByRule('margin-left')` will produce an array with all the elements in the page that have margin left.

```
getCssByRule (rule) {
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(e => {
    return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule)) !== 0
  })
  return elements
}
```

How to modify this function so I can also get the value of this computedValue? (e.g `30px`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get an `Array` of computed values, then you can modify your function like this:

```js
function getCssByRule(rule) {
  const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
    .filter(e => parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule)) !== 0)
    .map(e => window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule));

  return values;
}

console.log(getCssByRule('margin-left'));
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 20px"></div>
<div style="margin-left: 19px"></div>
<div></div>
<div style="margin-left: 18px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first map over the elements, then filter them using your rule. That way you'll need to `getComputedStyle` only once. Below will return an array of objects with `element => value` pairs

```js
function getCssByRule(rule) {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).map(element =>
    ({
      element,
      value: window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(rule)
    })
  ).filter(e => parseInt(e.value) !== 0);
}

console.log(getCssByRule('margin-left'));
```

```html
<div>
  Foo
</div>
<div id="foo" style="margin-left:10px">
  Bar
</div>
```

Comment: Darn, you're fast, beat me by a few seconds ;)